Como instalo buildozer en linux ubuntu paso a paso
hace unas semanas instale una maquina virtual con el sistema operativo de Ubuntu, pero ahora quiero saber como instalo buildozer, de antemano gracias

Por que no te sirve lo que dice la documentación?

Para instalar Buildozer en una máquina virtual con Ubuntu, puedes seguir estos pasos:

Actualizar los paquetes del sistema:

sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade


Instalar las dependencias necesarias:

sudo apt-get install -y git zip unzip openjdk-8-jdk python3-pip autoconf libtool pkg-config zlib1g-dev libncurses5-dev libncursesw5-dev libtinfo5 cmake libffi-dev libssl-dev


Instalar Cython:

pip3 install cython==0.29.24


Descargar Buildozer:

git clone https://github.com/kivy/buildozer.git


Instalar Buildozer:

cd buildozer
sudo python3 setup.py install


Crear un archivo de configuración para Buildozer:

buildozer init

Este comando creará un archivo buildozer.spec en el directorio actual. Puedes editar este archivo para configurar tus opciones de compilación.

Compilar tu aplicación:

buildozer android debug

Este comando compilará tu aplicación Kivy para Android en modo de depuración.
Si deseas compilar para una versión de lanzamiento, utiliza el siguiente comando:
buildozer android release

Recuerda que necesitarás tener instalado el SDK de Android y configurar las variables de entorno adecuadamente para que Buildozer pueda acceder a las herramientas de compilación de Android.

Por si acaso: El uso de IA generativa en SOes está prohibido y por qué publicar respuestas generadas por GPT y ChatGPT actualmente no es aceptable. Y por último: [es.so] no es un sitio de tutoriales. Haz el [tour] para conocer su funcionamiento.

Esto: sudo python3 setup.py install debería estar penado con cárcel... Dar permisos root a un script "random" comprometiendo la seguridad, a la vez que se instala un paquete en la isntalación de Python del sistema (lo que puede ya de por si romper el SO entero si no se hace a través del gestor de paquetes para no romper dependencias) es una práctica pésima... Instalar a nivel del usuario, los VENV y los contenedores existen para algo... Al menos es una máquina virtual y no el servidor de mi banco, espero... :)

Estoy tratando de instalarlo para la version de Ubuntu 24.04 y no puedo. Cuando hago el sudo apt-get install.. me sale estos avisos: Nota, seleccionando libncurses-dev en lugar de libncurses5-dev | Nota, seleccionando libncurses-dev en lugar de libncursesw5-dev | E: No se ha podido localizar el paquete libtinfo5
